# getting this error while executing jar file SessionFactory creation failedjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/ Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, executable-jar

i am getting below error while executing my jar file from command promt..but in eclipse when i am running my program it is working fine..not getting what is the exact cause of this error i have tried so many ways which i got from google...

```
SessionFactory creation failedjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/
Configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.valto.RetentionMain.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:26)

        at com.valto.RetentionDao.RetentionDao.getNotificationDays(RetentionDao.
java:48)
        at com.valto.RetentionMain.RetentionMainClass.cronTask(RetentionMainClas
s.java:19)
        at com.valto.RetentionMain.RetentionMainClass.main(RetentionMainClass.ja
va:97)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
        at com.valto.RetentionMain.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)

        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: have you included the hibernate jar in classpath(-cp) when you execute JAR from command line?

Comment: yes i included hibernate jar in classpath while executing from command prompt